# Trouble with slideToggle

Tags: jquery, addclass, slidetoggle, removeclass

I've got a minor problem with jQuery. In the HTML, I've got four links. I'm using addClass() and removeClass() to indicate which link has been selected, and that's working fine. However, I've got one specific link, #gallery, which initiates a slideToggle() with a div below the list. The thing is, if the div is showing, and the user selects a different link, the .selected class changes properly, but the div #book doesn't close. Any thoughts on how to resolve this? I've included all the code below, but ([I've got a fiddle going here](http://jsfiddle.net/tGW3D/), which is probably a lot easier.

Thanks in advance!

HTML

```
<ul>
<li><a class="link" href="#">Click here</a></li>
<li><a class="link" id="gallery" href="#">Click here</a></li>
<li><a class="link" href="#">Click here</a></li>
<li><a class="link" href="#">Click here</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="book"></div>
```

CSS

```
.link:link, .link:visited { text-decoration:none; }

#book { width:100px; height:100px; background:blue; }

.selected { color:red; }
```

JS

```
var $book = $('#book');
var $gallery = $('#gallery');

$book.hide();
$('a').click(function(){
$('a.selected').removeClass('selected');
$(this).addClass('selected');
});

$gallery.toggle(
function(){$book.slideDown('slow');},
function(){ 
    $book.slideUp('slow');
    $gallery.removeClass('selected');        
});
```

​

Answer (score 0):

`toggle` method is deprecated, you can use `slideToggle` instead, you can use an if statement and if target is not the element with ID of gallery slide the `#book` element.

```
$('a').click(function(e) {
    $('a.selected').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    if (e.target.id != 'gallery') $book.slideUp('slow');
});

$gallery.click(function() {
    $book.slideToggle('slow');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Z244D/